# Changing $scope inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to change `$scope` within controller from the wrapping `div` to the object I'm currently clicking on. My code is as follows:

```
var blogApp = angular.module('blogApp', ['ngSanitize', 'ngRoute']);

blogApp.controller('blogPostsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {   
    $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').success(function(data) {
        $scope.posts = data;
        $scope.postsLoaded = 'article--loaded';
    });

    $scope.getPost = function(postID) {
        var currentPost = document.getElementById('post-'+postID);
        $scope.postsLoaded = 'article--loaded';

        $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'+postID).success(function(data) {
            $scope.body = data.body;
            currentPost.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="body body--hidden" id="body-'+postID+'">'+$scope.body+'</div>');

            var currentBody = document.getElementById('body-'+postID);
            setTimeout(function() { currentBody.className = currentBody.className + ' body--visible'; }, 1000); 
            currentPost.classname = 'article one-half desk-one-whole';
        });
    };
});
```

html:

```
<div class="site-wrapper">
    <div class="grid-wrapper" ng-controller="blogPostsCtrl">
        <article ng-repeat="post in posts" ng-class="postsLoaded" class="article one-half desk-one-whole" id="post-{{post.id}}" ng-click="getPost(post.id)">
            <header><h2>{{post.title}}</h2></header>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I use function `getPost` inside controller and there I'm using `$scope`, but it's (as it should be) set for, like I said, global wrapper. How can I solve this? Please note I'm new to Angular, so I don't know if it's the valid way ;-)

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is. Can you update your question to clarify the problem you are having?

Comment: Okay, so again - my problem here is I want to change the `$scope` from every `article` to whichever `article` I currently clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Matthew Green. Your question a bit confused. But as far as I can see, you should use directives. 
Create a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and assign to it own $scope.

Hope that will help you.